# setup.cfgとtox.iniの使い分け

Tags: python, setuptools, tox

## 環境

- Python 3.7
- tox 3.13

## 背景

以下のツールを利用して、Pythonのパッケージを作成しています。

- [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf)：Formatter
- [isort](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort)：Formatter
- [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/)：Lintter
- [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org)：Lintter
- [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

上記のツールの設定情報は、可能な限り1つのファイルにまとめて記載したいです。
Pylintとflake8の設定情報が互いに依存しているためです。例えば、「flake8では1行の文字数をチェックするから、pylintでは1行の文字数をチェックしない」などです。

### Formatter, Lintterの設定

[toxパッケージのtox.ini](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/blob/master/tox.ini)には、flake8の設定情報が記載されています。

```
[flake8]
max-complexity = 22
max-line-length = 99
ignore = E203, W503, C901, E402, B011
```

私はこれに倣って、`tox.ini`にFormatter, Lintterの設定情報を記載しようとしました。
しかし、yapfだけは`tox.ini`に記載した設定情報を読み込めません。コマンドライン引数で設定ファイルを指定できず、デフォルトでは`tox.ini`を読み込まないためです。
`setup.cfg`に記載した設定情報は読み込めます。
https://github.com/google/yapf#id7

また、pandasでは[setup.cfg](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/setup.cfg)にflake8, yapfの設定情報が記載されていました。
※tox.iniは存在しない

以上のことから私は、Formatter, Linterの設定情報は`setup.cfg`に書いた方が良いと思いました。

## 質問

Formatter, Linterの設定は、`setup.cfg`か`tox.ini`どちらに記載すればよいですか？

また、`setup.cfg`と`tox.ini`はどう使い分ければよいですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setup.cfg` を参照するか `tox.ini` を参照するか、あるいは別のファイル `.pylintrc` や `pytest.ini` を参照するかは、各ライブラリによって任されています。

このため、それぞれのライブラリの組み合わせ次第では、「どちらを使えば良いか」ではなく「両方使う必要がある」かもしれません。

今後は `pyproject.toml` に集約されていくのかもしれませんが、 [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) 等の一部のライブラリは現状 `pyproject.toml` 未対応ですし、逆に [towncrier](https://pypi.org/project/towncrier/) などの一部のライブラリは最新版では `pyproject.toml` しか参照しないものもあります。

仕方がないので、今は過渡期だとあきらめて、自分が便利そうだと思うファイルに書くのがよさそうです。